# Command-line gunzip on macOS 12.7 Monterey (M1 Mac mini) gives OK with gunzip -tv filename.gz and NOT OK with gunzip -ltv filename.gz

Tags: command-line

The situation:

1. The file php-8.2.11.tar.gz is downloaded from https://www.php.net/downloads.php
2. At the command line, running `gunzip -tv php-8.2.11.tar.gz` gives output which includes `OK`. However, running `gunzip -ltv php-8.2.11.tar.gz` gives output which includes `NOT OK`.

(I hope that posting this information about the php-8.2.11.tar.gz archive does not violate any copyrights regarding the archive contents.)

As an additional note, the output from `gunzip -V` is `Apple gzip 353.100.22`

Does anyone know as to why one set of options gives OK and the other gives NOT OK?

Answer (score 0):

It's evidently a bug: `gzip -ltv foo.gz` seems to report `NOT OK` on any file. As a workaround, you can invoke `-l` and `-t` separately:

```
gunzip -lv php-8.2.11.tar.gz
gunzip -tv php-8.2.11.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

In the terminal (in Ventura) the man page for gunzip gives

```
SYNOPSIS
     gzip [-cdfhkLlNnqrtVv] [-S suffix] file [file [...]]
     gunzip [-cfhkLNqrtVv] [-S suffix] file [file [...]]
     zcat [-fhV] file [file [...]]
```

Thus -l is not an option for gunzip - so your second command has an invalid parameter which might be the source of the NOT OK.

Comment: That's not it: `gzip -ltv foo.gz` also outputs `NOT OK`. The omission of `-l` for `gunzip` is evidently a documentation bug, since it and similar options (e.g. `-t`) work identically with `gzip` and `gunzip`.